# How to take only last response from async/await function

Tags: javascript, async-await

How to ignore all old called `async/await` functions if multiple async/await functions is called.

For example, this is my example.

```
let isLoading = false;

const onResponse = dateTime => {
  console.log(dateTime);
  isLoading = false;
}

const asyncFunction = async () => {
  await delay(1000);
  return new Date();
}
```

Now for example, if I called the function `asyncFunction` 3 times within 1 seconds, then I will take `onResponse` 3 times and my variable `isLoading` work improperly.

```
function loadData() {
  isLoading = true;
  asyncFunction.then(onResponse);
}
```

How can I take response only from last call and ignore all earlier others.

Comment: There is no native method to cancel a promise is js

Comment: @MaheerAli so is there any way to handle this case?

Comment: Just overwrite the variable, and it will always contain the last value. If you want to wait till all three promises are resolved, `await Promise.all`.

Comment: You can simply make it debounce. https://medium.com/@TCAS3/debounce-deep-dive-javascript-es6-e6f8d983b7a1

Comment: The point of debouncing it to ignore the stacking events, not cancelling the ones prior.

Comment: @RoboRobok yes it will not cancel that the function is already called and executed. But it will cancel called function (promise) that not yet executed.

Comment: OP wants to ignore the *old* calls, just like aborting fetch or Ajax.

Comment: @Robo Robok yes this is what I meant.

Comment: Then I think the best way to do this, @RoboRobok`s solution simple and easy to apply

Comment: @NickViatick I have just wanted to add a debouncing idea with an example. If it is appliable for your case, you can consider that as well. I hope that one of the solutions helps you.

Comment: @NickViatick are you ready to select the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I would just store some value and increment it every time you call your async function. Then, in the handler you can check if that value is still the same. If not, just return - it means that there was another call afterwards.

Comment: This is also my thought,

Im just wondering that is there any proper way for this case.

Comment: Like Maheer Ali said in the comment before, there is no built-in way to cancel the promise.

Comment: @jonatjano but that way the slowest response wins, not the latest promise.

Answer (score 2):

My answer was removed because I had sent directly link of debouncing. I have just wanted to explain what was in my head.

Here is the my solution that is like the below example. You can improve or change the code block depending on your needing. Simply it's canceled the previous calling. In my opinion, It's not the perfect solution. But one of the solutions to the problem.

```
const onResponse = dateTime => {
  console.log(dateTime);
}

const asyncFunction = async () => {
  await setTimeout(() => {}, 1000);
  return new Date();
}

function debounce (callback, delay) {
    let timeout;

    return function (then) {
        const that = this;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => callback.apply(that, []).then(then), delay);
    };
}

const debouncedFunction = debounce(asyncFunction, 100);

debouncedFunction(onResponse);
debouncedFunction(onResponse);
debouncedFunction(onResponse);
debouncedFunction(onResponse);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

here's an implemetation of [Robo Robok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4403732/robo-robok)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60502545/10153945) (if you upvote me, upvote him too)

```js
let isLoading = false;
let promiseCounter = 0;

const delay = time => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => {res()}, time))

// use a destructuring assignement
const onResponse = ({dateTime, promiseId}) => {
  // refuse promise if it was not the last
  if (promiseId !== promiseCounter) {return;}
  // reset counter to avoir overflow on really long run
  promiseCounter = 0;
  
  // do what needs to be done
  console.log("onResponse", dateTime);
  isLoading = false;
}

const asyncFunction = async () => {
  const promiseId = ++promiseCounter;
  await delay(1000);
  return {dateTime: new Date(), promiseId};
}

function loadData() {
  isLoading = true;
  asyncFunction().then(onResponse);
}

(async ()=>{
  // simulate multiple calls with a total interval > delay of one resposne
  console.log("first call at", new Date())
  loadData()
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    await delay(30);
    loadData()
  }
  console.log("last call at", new Date())
})()
```

doc : [destructuring assignement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the last completed result something like this should work:

```
let finalResult;

const workFunc = async () => {
   finalResult = new Date();
}

await Promise.all([ workFunc(), workFunc(), workFunc() ]);

console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code defines a function `latest` that can be applied to a function to ensure only the latest call is run to completion.

A variable `curr` records the latest invocation by storing the latest promise. A function is configured in the `then` position to mediate continuation. Progress along the promise chain is only permitted if the promise in progress is equal to `curr`. ie. a subsequent invocation has not overwritten `curr` in the interim.

So the following code prints out: `stale two`.

```js
function latest(fn) {
    let curr = null
    return (...args) => {
        let p = fn(...args).then((result) =>  { 
            if(p === curr) return result
            else throw 'stale' 
        })
        curr = p
        return p
    }
}

const doSomething = (v, ms) => new Promise((r)=> setTimeout(() => r(v), ms))
const latestDoSomething = latest(doSomething)

latestDoSomething('one', 100).then(console.log).catch(console.log)
latestDoSomething('two', 100).then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.All:

```
await Promise.all([Call1(), Call2(), Call3(),...]).then(values => { 
  //values is [value1,value2,....,lastValue]
  console.log(values[values.length-1]); last value is in the last entry
});
```

Comment: Calling three times is just my example.

it can be called more than hundred times.